# how to convert Range.Inclusive to NumericRange.Inclusive[Char] type?

Tags: scala

I want to get:

```
val s: String ="12ab"
```

i tried:

```
//it is ok
List(('1', '2'), ('a', 'b')).map { case (a, b) => a to b mkString } mkString

// it is invalid
List((1, 2), ('a', 'b')).map{case (a,b)=> a to b mkString } mkString
```

How can I make the second example compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that using `Int` and `Char` in the same list makes it a `List[(AnyVal, AnyVal)]`. You can use pattern matching to get around the problem:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(List((1, 2), ('a', 'b')).map {
    case (x: Int, y: Int) => x to y mkString
    case (x: Char, y: Char) => x to y mkString
  } mkString)
}
```

Yields:

```
12ab
```